# Документация проекта/проектов + связи

Tags: php, архитектура, проектирование, документация

Есть несколько проектов, взаимодействующих друг с другом по http api или console api или еще как-нибудь.

Грубо говоря, проект состоит из приложений, приложения состоят из компонентов, компоненты состоят из интерфейсов и классов.

Необходимо описать все это, сделать какую-нибудь документацию, чтобы пришедший человек мог узнать как какой-нибудь проект устроен изнутри, из каких компонентов состоит, описание возможностей компонентов и понял взаимодействие между компонентами и проектами.

Подробно описывать методы классов нет необходимости, можно просто описать роль, цель, возможности. Или, может быть, только интерфейсы.

Какие есть инструменты для подобного документирования? Желательно с графиками отношений и более или менее удобным обновлением информации несколькими людьми, т.к. все постоянно дорабатывается.

На данный момент есть опыт работы с draw.io.

В принципе это все можно описать текстом + делать ссылки на draw.io, но может быть есть что-то еще.

UPD.

Примерно вижу это так:

- Страница с диаграммой взаимодействия проектов (Что-то типа схемы базы данных)
- Подобная страница с диаграммой взаимодействия компонентов внутри проекта
- При переходе в проект видно описание и список компонентов и связанные проекты
- При переходе в компонент видно описание, интерфейсы и связанные компоненты

Comment: Конечно [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) не решит все ваши проблемы, но советую посмотреть в его сторону.

Comment: Lucidchart - похож на draw.io, но значительно удобнее и имеют больше контента. Visual paradigm, Enterprise Architect. Visio.

Comment: http api я описываю через api blueprint и генерирую с помощью aglio. Для документирования кода подходит PHPDoc, если, конечно соответствующие комментарии в коде имеются.

Answer (score 2):

Для документации api на php, есть, например: [Swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) и [API Platfor](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform).

Если проекты на фреймворках, то для них есть расширения:

- Symfony: [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/current/index.html);
- Yii2: [yii2-apidoc](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-apidoc)(офф) и [yii2-swagger](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-swagger)

Они генерируют страницу документации на основе комментариев в самом коде или отдельным конфиг файлом.
Будет почти всегда актуальной + можно заодно и потыкать посмотреть, как работает.

Но, это, скорей, последние два пункта...

Для генераций диаграмм, знаю ток [PlantUML](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml) ([например](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/PPBDYjim58NtVegxYg4bpCnsmEtys7G6qf_6Xg6heh7Lrf1OHfOJiajIkcgXBz27225kKf8uht3rHhrEwupYB2u8oJxdV4UwoXIJAk_tB1Og8G5_OO5RcWN-naAFhPIEup1EMQBWWJz-zBaSS7coVPscHtikK-o6PTnYkH99td-aVvhQq7vXIC8blF82E4kbYF9GPMTAZBAN8LFyiv0Z9sIo5OgUaCxmIwmuhVD4EHVdhK7CXqulpbGh4r8vgOn37ebXKW750_hTZ6tOjV-xKtAolWk2TsrSuWntUeobdZm7t538AUqiQBQurT-n02p1_0eBgzOWlGCr2VfUnxiDu1byag8FDHGyt7bT3mvKDc7PSFt6XNzizXxEXhTTr-l2pGVOuu3h-RVGkNzz7y35-G7igUHwqO2YZ0KkzLTSwnyLYPu2pWbZXoMkgvkWMUcVuB_l7B7Zp8hugOj9QXHPbrUInRog3FG4ZD8skAfgezEIpcTwJFEjUHCdR-CIQ5cQKVTYVvfcHbBpegzu4bMl-Yy0), если что-то такого надо)

но, чтоб объединить...
если ток сохранить диаграмму как картинку и в пунктах "*description*" добавить:
`<img alt="example" src="../images/example.png" />` `![example](../images/example.png)` (в доках надо посмотреть, у кого как)

Из сторонних, есть ещё:
OpenAPI-generator, ReDoc, DapperDox